# By which year did smiths achieve the ability to handle metal in an exact way that's necessary for the printing press?

Tags: gutenberg

Gutenberg did invent his printing skills 1440 and reportedly used his skills as a goldsmith to do so. To get a good printing quality his work had to be very precise.

By which year did goldsmiths or other smiths acquire the necessary skills to produce work that was precise enough for what Gutenberg did?

Comment: Did you mean "achieve the required ability" and "smiths acquire the necessary skills"?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure metal is required at all.

Answer (score 1):

[Gutenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printing_press) himself developed the [hand mould](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(printing)) needed to (quickly) cast the letters of a uniform size for the movable type. That would have been around 1440. These letters were then inserted into the "screw presses" in use at the time. His new method would have been, as we now say, "hot off the presses" (pun intended).

Gutenberg had not been the developer of "movable" type. But he did design the mechanism for making the letters fit neatly into a "matrix" for printing, making the typesetting process much easier.

Gutenberg's invention also ensured that the letters could be imprinted on paper or cloth by inserting an inked surface between them. (Previously, the inking had to be applied to the letters themselves, a much clumsier method of printing.) But the [screw presses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_press) he used were based on much earlier (first century A.D.) designs developed by the Romans for wine and olive oil pressing.

Comment: Are you saying that before Gutenberg the hand mould wasn't used for any other purpose?

Comment: @Christian: Certainly not for printing, its main use. Possibly for "injection" moulding. But the metallurgy (heating/cooling mechanisms) of the time was inadequate for more than small production runs, outside of printing. The idea of "multiple" production was barely understood, and "mass production" (as we understand it), not at all. Gutenberg was arguably the father of modern "mass production," through his printing machine.